# Pull Data from Hive to SQL Server without duplicates using Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

Sorry I'm new in Apache Nifi. So i made a data flow regarding pulling data from Hive and storing it in SQL. There is no error on my data flow, the only problem is, its pulling data repeatedly.

My Data flow is consists of the following:

1. **SelectHiveQL**
2. **SplitAvro**
3. **ConvertAvroToJson**
4. **ConvertJsonTOSQL**
5. **PutSQL**

For example my table in hive have 20 rows only but when i run the data flow and check my table in MS SQL. It saved 5,000 rows. The SelectHiveQL pulled the data repeatedly.

What do i need to do so it will only pull 20 rows or just the exact number of rows in my Hive Table?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SelectHiveQL](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.SelectHiveQL/index.html) (like many NiFi processors) runs on a user-specified schedule. To get a processor to only run once, you can set the run schedule to something like 30 sec, then start and immediately stop the processor. The processor will be triggered once, and stopping it does not interrupt that current execution, it just causes it not to be scheduled again.

Another way might be to set the run schedule to something very large, such that it would only execute once per some very long time interval (days, years, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Now processors have run once option as well. If you set the run schedule to your desired time but want to only test the flow then you can choose the option run once which will allow to run processor only once and it will stop afterwards irrespective of its schedule timing.

After configuring the processor just do right click on it and click run once. After a few seconds refresh the whole canvas to see the result in queue.